# Implementing __mul__ for timeseries in Python for different items

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I am trying to implement a piecewise constant function class in python.
I am wondering what is the best way to implement these `__mul__` and `__add__` functions.
Essentially, I want to be able to handle two cases: multiply by a constant or multiply by another timeseries.

For multiply or adding the constants, I am just going to return a constant times the values with the existing timepoints. For multiply by timeseries, will construct a new series with timepoints being the union of the timepoints and multiply / add them one by one.

Whilst I know how to do both, should I just do

```
if type(other) == int or type(other) == float:
    # implementation
else:
    # implementation
```

This looks very ugly to me. In C++, one would be able to do an operator overload with different input type. What is the Pythonic way of doing this? In particular, I am concerned that I might have missed out an eligible type in the statement with a statement like this one

```
if type(other) == int or type(other) == float:
```

Also, the implementation of add, mul, sub, div function implementation will almost be identical (except the operator bit). Is there a way of writing one function which each individual one of them would just call?

Essentially I was thinking about a method like

```
def operation_by_const(self, operator, other):
    return PiecewiseConstant(self.times, self.values .... other)
```

where ... should be replaced by apply the add/mul/div/sub operator from np.array to const, but I am not sure what is the correct syntax for this in Python. Even though this function does not save much ink for multiplying constant case, for implementation of timeseries multiplied by a timeseries, it would save a lot of copy pasting.

Here is the rest of the code

```
from bisect import bisect_left
from functools import cached_property
import numpy as np


class PiecewiseConstant:
    def __init__(self, times: np.array, values: np.array):

        # entire non-empty
        assert(len(times) == len(values))
        assert(len(times))

        for i, j in zip(times[0:-1], times[1:]):
            if i >= j:
                raise ValueError("Time series needs to have increasing indices")

        self.times = times
        self.values = values

    def __getitem__(self, time):

        if time < self.times[0]:
            return self.values[0]

        time_index = bisect_left(self.times, time)

        # if time is greater than all our time points or less than the time corresponding to the index
        if time_index == len(self.times) or time < self.times[time_index]:
            return self.values[time_index - 1]

        return self.values[time_index]
    
    def __setitem__(self, time):
        raise NotImplementedError("Setting values of timeseries through indexing is not allowed")
    
    def __mul__(self, other):
        pass

    def __add__(self, other):
        pass
```

EDIT: I have now done this. Would appreciate some feedback.

```
def apply_binary_operator(self, operator, other):
    assert isinstance(other, PiecewiseConstant)
    if self.times == other.times:
        return PiecewiseConstant(self.times, f"self.values.{operator}(other.values)")
    
    else:
        times = []
        values = []

        self_it = 0
        other_it = 0
        self_time = self.times[self_it]
        other_time = other.values[other_it]

        while self_it != len(self.times) and other_it != len(other.times):
            if self_time <= other_time:
                times.append(self_time)
                values.append(eval(f"self.values[self_it].{operator}(other[self_time])"))
                self_it += 1
                if self_time == other_time:
                    other_it += 1
                    other_time = other.times[other_it]
                self_time = self.times[self_it]
                
            else:
                times.append(other_time)
                values.append(eval(f"other.values[other_it].{operator}(self[other_time])"))
                other_it += 1 

def __mul__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, PiecewiseConstant):
        return self.apply_binary_operator("__mul__", other)
```

Comment: You should use `isinstance(other, int)` and similiarly for floats, otherwise you don't include any subclasses of those.

Comment: @lost1 In case of two time series, will the length be equal, for either mul or add?

Comment: No, they wont be, i will figure out an array which takes the union of the times, then just compute it at that time. Otherwise, i can just use numpy implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python there is no syntax-bound polymorphism, as you ask, although similar behavior can be achieved via decorators. `functools.singledispatch` being one (but I think it would not work with methods, because it just looks at the first argument, you'd have to build your own or use a 3rdy party lib).

Anyway, this is more or less a digression: the more common pattern is an if/elif block to select the arguments inside your method - as you found out.

You also found out about `isinstance` which is way better than `type(obj) == mytype`, which is good. You can do `from numbers import Number` and then use `isinstance(obj, Number)` to match all numeric types (int, float, complex, Fraction, Decimal and custom defined classes)

Also, from Python 3.10 there is the `match/case` construct if one happens to dislike `if/elif`. As it is more verbose, and doesn't really add functionality in this case, keeping `if/elif` is simpler.

Now, getting into the "good parts": you don't have to pass the operator around as a string, and then resort to "eval" to perform your computations. Functions are first class objects, remember? you can either pass an `op = lambda x, y: x * y` as your operator to the method, or, to be even more elegant and a bit more performant, you can do `from operator import mul`, and pass that around.

Also, the `assert` in the beginning of your function is not really a common practice in Python: it will blow at runtime, not at compile time, and as such, you can just leave the guard off, and let it blow up whenever the passed in argumentsobjects don't meet one of the interface requirements in the code itself. You will get a `TypeError` instead - but with the advantage that if someone builds a type that is compatible with your timeseries for the purposes of this operation, it will be able to benefit from this code: that is calling "duck typing".
The better practice to assert what is being passed to the function would be, rather than the "assert" statement, annotate the whole code and use a tool for static type checking, such as `mypy`.

It is a bit bureaucratic for 90% of end-uses of the language (as in contrast to writing lib/framework code that will be used by others), but then, so is inserting the `assert` statements.

That said, I rewrote some parts of your code with more idiomatic Python -
One thing that I was in doubt to change is to use the "except StopIteration" in the large block instead of the specific "while" condition: if you prefere that, the iter/next protocol accept a sentinel value you can test for in the while (check the historic editions of this post to see the example).

```
from typing import Callable
from operator import mul, add


class PiecewiseConstant:

    # bellow, lightweight typehinting in the parameter annotations which are already useful
    # for a human glancing at the code. 
    def apply_binary_operator(self, operator: Callable, other: PiecewiseConstant) -> PiecewiseConstant:
        
        if self.times == other.times:
            # if self.values is a custom class, the operators from operator module
            # will also call their respective dunder methods (__mul__ and __add__)
            return PiecewiseConstant(self.times, operator(self.values, other.values)) 
            # otherwise, if ".values" is a plain list, this will work:
            
            return PiecewiseConstant(self.times, [operator(own_v, other_v) for own_v, other_v in zip(self.values, other.values)]) 
            # these, of course, assuming your __init__ has  a provision when getting an actual object
            # and not a string to be evalued
        
        # there is a "return" when the `if` matches above. No need for
        # an extra identation level with an `else` block here:
        times = []
        values = []

        # Using the iterator protocol
        #  This allows changing all "index increment" and "fetch element at index" code
        # ocurrences for a single "next" call: your example were missing
        # one "fetch element at index" in one of the occurrences.
        self_it, self_times = enumerate(self.times)
        other_it, other_times = enumerate(other.times)
    
        try:

            self_it, self_time = next(self_times)
            other_it, other_time = next(other_times)
            while True: # we exit when one of the series is exhausted
                if self_time <= other_time:
                    times.append(self_time)
                    op1 = self.values[self_it]
                    op2 = other[self_time]
                    self_it, self_time = next(self_times)
                    # I don't know about the precisions/noise you
                    # have in your data - but you might want to check
                    # "math.isclose" instead of "==" here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose
                    if self_time == other_time:
                        other_it, other_time = next(other_times)
                else:
                    times.append(other_time)
                    op1 = other.values[other_it]
                    op2 = self[other_time]
                    other_it, other_time = next(other_times)
                    
                # refactoring to a single append is optional, of course,
                # but whenever there is code "doing things" I prefer
                # to have it in a single place if there is an option.
                values.append(operator(op1, op2))
        except StopIteration:
            # whenever a series tries to advance beyond its end,
            # a stopIteration is raised when "next" is called.
            # 
            # this is the _same_ protocol that is used in Python's
            # native "for" loops. The custom stepping of this task
            # requires us to make the handling explicit
            pass
        #  return code missing in your snippet.- guessing it would be:
        return self.__class__(np.array(times), np.array(values))
        # using "self.__class__ allows the code to work effectively if your class
        # is inherited: you return instances of the subclass, instead of
        # hardcoding the class where this method is defined.
            

    def __mul__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, PiecewiseConstant):
            return self.apply_binary_operator(mul, other)
        ...

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, PiecewiseConstant):
            return self.apply_binary_operator(add, other)
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I need to take a bit more time to digest this. Was not familiar with Callable type you used here.

Comment: -> PiecewiseConstant this type hinting own class is unfortunately not available in python 3.7 we are using, but yes, I would have done this.

Comment: Ah - just use it as a string, by adding quotes. - still good for both human readers and the tooling - "PiecewiseConstant"

Comment: return PiecewiseConstant(self.times, [operator(own_v, other_v) for own_v, other_v in zip(self.values, other.values)]) 
 -- should this part also be changed to self.__class__?

Comment: do you mean write def apply_binary_operator(self, operator: Callable, other: PiecewiseConstant) -> "PiecewiseConstant":  for the method definition?

Comment: def apply_binary_operator(self, operator: Callable, other: "PiecewiseConstant") -> "PiecewiseConstant":  - both occurrences have to be parenthized.

In newer python there is also `typing.Self` for this case.

Comment: As for the first returns statement: yes, it can also be  `self.__class__` -